# Accessing the index of the current interation of loop variable while looping through a string array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Java novice here.  I have a problem that I'm sure must have a simple solution but I've been searching all over and can't seem to find anything that answers my question.

I'm trying to figure out what expression to use in order to get the index of the current interation of loop variable when looping through a string array in a for loop.  Specifically, I'm trying to store some information acquired in the for loop in a different array (I think there's a more efficient way to do this but we haven't covered more than single-dimensional arrays in class yet so no matter), at a parallel index as the current interation.  For example, I'm trying to store the information yielded from the second iteration of the loop in the [1] index of the other array.  I'm trying to do it by saying new_array[i.indexOf()] = blah blah blah, where i is the for loop variable.  Unfortunately, it's telling me that since it's a string it can't convert it to an int or something, and in eclipse the dialogues that pop up only reference how to access the index of a character within that string and not the index of the string within the array being looped over.

If somebody could help me out with this I would be so thankful.

Comment: Instead of new_array[i.indexOf()] have you tried just new_array[i]?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work since it's a string index being iterated over.  The loop variable always contains a string so you reference an index of an array with array[i].  (Specifically--"type mismatch: cannot convert from string to int".)

Comment: you really should paste the code, it is not at all clear how you are trying to solve this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're using a foreach loop. If so, you need to introduce a counter:

```
int i = 0;
for (String s : stringArray) {
    // do something with s, which is at position i in the array
    i++; // increment counter ready for next iteration
}
```

Alternatively, you can revert to a standard for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
    String s = stringArray[i];
    // do something with s, which is at position i in the array
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I guess it's not possible to access the index when you're using an enhanced loop?

Comment: No. Use the enhanced loop (called a *foreach* loop) when you *don't* need the index. Otherwise, use a regular for loop.